# How do I find out which stored procedure sent an email?

Tags: sql-server, email, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

We have an email that is being sent to us from SQL Server that we want to stop. How do I find out which stored procedure is sending that email so I can modify/disable it?

What I've tried

- Searching through all stored procedures via `sys.all_sql_modules` for words in the email subject and body text.

  ```
  SELECT *
  FROM sys.all_sql_modules AS asm
  INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON o.object_id = asm.object_id
  WHERE asm.definition LIKE '%*[subject/body words]*%'
  ```
- I've looked through the `sysmail_*` tables and I **have** found my email being sent but I haven't found a way to trace it back to a stored procedure.

  ```
  SELECT TOP 100 * 
  FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_sentitems AS ss
  WHERE ss.subject LIKE '%keyword%'
  ```

Comment: I don't think you can. You would have to have something in the email to indicate where it came from. Once it is sent the system doesn't care where it originated from.

Comment: What were your results for the first thing you tried?  Was it too much to sift through or did it not return anything?

Comment: @Dave.Gugg I got no results in all_sql_modules.

Comment: You could grab Redgate's SQL Search.  A free tool that will search through all your databases and find the subject/body words, if it is indeed in a SP.  I use it a ton.

Answer (score 3):

you could search sys.modules for the string

> sp_send_dbmail

Then look at all the hits.  OTOH how do you know it was sent from a PROC at all?  It could be an ad-hoc query calling sp_send_dbmail, or an agent job, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply create a server side trace and with filter for `textdata` like '%sp_send_dbmail%'

Then just run the trace for 1 day, and then you can figure out which SP is sending out db mail. This way, you can surely find out whether the email is sent via a stored proc or via an ad-hoc query (like inside a SSRS report?) or from a job step.